# How to perform validation before decoding the raw JSON?

Tags: php, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, api-security

We are building an API Framework in PHP (Hacklang) and will be using [json-schema](https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/) from OPIS to implement validation of JSON input in the request body.

OWASP recommends implementing validations on minimum and maximum value range check for numerical parameters - [Link](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Input_Validation_Cheat_Sheet.html#goals-of-input-validation)

But looks like json-schema cannot perform validations on JSON encoded strings (raw input to the API) - https://opis.io/json-schema/2.x/php-validator.html

[image]

By first deserialising the input, I think we lose many of the benefits that schema validation provides. For eg., if the maxItems of an array field in the validation schema is 1 but the client provides a billion items, we would be deserialising everything only to throw an exception later.

Is there a way to perform validation without/while deserialising the raw input? How are open source API Frameworks handling this concern?

Comment: You could restrict the maximum size of the JSON string before using `json_decode()`.

Comment: Do you want to validate if it's a valid JSON? or do you want to Validate the content of JSON?

Comment: @VasoGamdelidze We want to do both.

Comment: @KIKOSoftware Thats a good idea. I feel there could be performance improvements in doing validation as a part of deserialisation. (We could terminate early in case of errors)

Comment: From PHP 8.3, we would have a new function, json_validate, which can detect if JSON is valid. And another part of validating json string before decoding could decrease your performance. You can take a look at this repo. Maybe it can give some new ideas. https://github.com/halaxa/json-machine